# How to practice and improve sense of rythm guitar .?

Tags: guitar

How to be creative with rhythm guitar playing? I am an intermediate guitar player and have the knowledge of what chords in a key.

Answer (score 5):

The best tip to learn rhythm guitar is to play with other people and/or against different rhythm section styles. Try to find a drummer to jam with. Backing tracks [[1]](http://www.projazzlab.com/)[[2]](http://www.pgmusic.com/)[[3]](https://singularsound.com/landing-pages/beatbuddy-main/) will work to an extent but the problem is that they never change. And an important aspect of rhythm playing is reacting to what the rest of the band is playing. You'll react to the feel and the rhythms that they are playing and play something that you probably wouldn't have otherwise. Then what *you* play feeds back to *them*, etc.

Besides that here are some other tips:

- Use a metronome
- If you haven't already, learn about meter and how to count. Do it all the time until it becomes second nature.
- Learn to read rhythm notation and find a bunch to practice. Even if you aren't going to be reading charts in a performance context, the act of having to figure out the rhythms and perfect them will be a huge help. There are [apps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rhythm-sight-reading-trainer/id396302174?mt=8) to help with this.
- Learn the idiomatic differences between different genres. Different genres will require different rhythms and it's your job to know what will fit well.
- Know the fretboard well. Learn different voicings and inversions. In other words learn more chords. Go well beyond the typical barre chords that you start off with.
- Practice things like polyrhythms, syncopation, and odd time signatures. Again, even if you don't intend to play music that makes use of them, it's good practice.
- Tweak your metronome so that it's not playing every beat. Try setting it to play only beats 2 & 4 (or adjusting the tempo to approximate it). Then try 1 & 3, or even just 4, whatever. The point is that you'll have to work a little harder to keep the time when given less information. You're playing around the metronome rather than just following it.
- Speaking of that, remember that the metronome isn't just a traffic cop telling you to slow down or speed up. Pretend the metronome is a drummer. It's your jam session buddy. Try playing interactively with it. Play slight ahead of the beat to create a pushed feel or behind it to drag it back. The metronome won't react to you, but the good thing about that is that it puts the onus on you to create those feels.
- Play drums if you can. Access to a real drum set can be expensive and loud, but even tapping out beats on your desk will work. Being very familiar with how beats are put together is a huge help.
- Most importantly, just do it a lot.